# Get client ip address from fetch response

Tags: javascript, fetch

Is it possible to get the client Ip address from the response of ta fetch?  Something like this

```
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("My IP Address: ", response.originIP);
    })
```

Comment: Not sure what you need, is it simply getting the client IP on the client side?

Comment: Also is the response comes back from your server or from a different service?

Comment: Yes I need to get the client IP. The response comes from server.

Comment: from which server? are you sending the response? do you have access to that server? or is it out of your reach?

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. All the available methods of the fetch response are listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

You could however create a web service to return an IP address: [How to get client's IP address using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can use this to get your client's *public* IP address:

```
async function getClientIp() {
    const { ip } = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', { method: 'GET' })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    
    return ip || "0.0.0.0";
}
```

To know more about `fetch`: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).

To know more about `ipify`: [here](https://www.ipify.org).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).